# TypeError: is not a constructor with Node and Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote code below and I have a `TypeError: Server is not a constructor` and I don't see why and how to fixe it.

Server.js code :

```
const express = require('express');

class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.app = express();

        this.app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.send('Hello World');
        })
    }

    start() {
        this.app.listen(8080, function() {
            console.log('MPS application is listening on port 8080 !')
        });
    }
}
```

app.js code :

```
const Server = require('./Server');
const express = require('express');

const server = new Server();

server.start();
```

Comment: did you export the Server from `Server.js`? what does app.js say when you ask it to `console.log(Server)`

Comment: add `module.exports = Server` at the end of your `Server.js` code

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Krzeszewski and @ Banujan Balendrakumar it was that !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not export the `Server` class. In your 'Server.js' file, do this:

```js
export default Server {
...
}
```

and leave your 'app.js' like this:

```js
const Server = require("./Server");
```

**The above method only works with ES6 and up, if not using ES6:**

```js
class Server {
...
}

module.exports = Server;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `export` your class before import anywhere,

Add the following line at the end of your `Server.js`

```
module.exports = Server
```

**ES6**

```js
export default Server {
 // you implementation
}
```